# reference table by name provided by a function output in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

Say I have a string in the field A1 which is: "table 1". On another sheet is a table named "table_1".
Now I wanted to subsitute the space in "table 1" for a underscore.
I can do that with the Substitute function but I am not able to reference the table with the output of the SUBSTITUTE function:
`=SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","__")`
This will only return the string but Excel does not interpret this as the table name.
Putting this through INDIRECT or chaining a TEXT function did not work either:
`=INDIRECT(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","_"))`

I want to do this in order to display some matrices(formatted as tables) from a separate sheet in my main sheet.

Thanks!

Comment: Works fine for me. Have you checked the output of the `Substitute`? There may be a space before or after the string. Also, your first example has two underscores ("`__`") and not one ("`_`")

Comment: goddamnit, I had a typo in the table name. This has cost me way too much time... Thanks for verification!

Answer (score 0):

Change the formula `=SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","__")` to `=SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","_")`